# ASP.NET Core SignalR Scaleout with Redis

Tags: redis, asp.net-core, signalr

Setting up SignalR with a pub/sub Redis backplane is incredibly easy in ASP.NET - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis).

Can we do this in ASP.NET Core today? Are the ASP.NET Core packages ready  this?  It doesn't need to be this easy to configure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's there, my colleagues recently implemented it. But since we have a reverse proxy in front of the app, this is giving us problems (make sure your proxy accepts alsothe HTTP Update verb.)

Since the new IOC model everything seems to be very easily configurable.

Use: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server. I'm not sure (pretty sure it's not) production ready though: https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/aspnetcore-dev/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server

Best way would be to check out the GitHub code. Maybe you make your own implementation that sooths you best (for a non easy way).

Comment: It is there, however, like you've implied there's no scaleout option with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server`.  Also, [that package has been deprecated](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server). SignalR for ASP.NET Core is being rebuilt, and, will include Redis backplane with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Redis` - [see here](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR).